# Ошибка в расширении Emmet LiveStyle в консоли js

Tags: javascript

Собственно данная ошибка выводится в хроме в любой складке .

[image: собственно возможно скрин поможет понять что не так]

```
 (function(f){if(typeof exports==="object"&&typeof module!=="undefined"){module.exports=f()}else if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define([],f)}else{var g;if(typeof window!=="undefined"){g=window}else if(typeof global!=="undefined"){g=global}else if(typeof self!=="undefined"){g=self}else{g=this}g.contentScript = f()}})(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

/**
 * CSSOM LiveStyle patcher: maps incoming updates to browser’s 
 * CSS Object Model. This is a very fast method of applying 
 * incoming updates from LiveStyle which is also works in any
 * modern browser environment.
 */
var pathfinder = require('livestyle-pathfinder');
var splitBy = require('./lib/split');

/**
 * Returns hash with available stylesheets. The keys of hash
 * are absolute urls and values are pointers to StyleSheet objects
 * @return {Object}
 */
var stylesheets = module.exports.stylesheets = function() {
    return findStyleSheets(document.styleSheets);
};

/**
 * Updates given stylesheet with patches
 * @param  {CSSStyleSheet} stylesheet
 * @param  {Array} patches
 * @returns {StyleSheet} List of `insertRule` and `deleteRule` commands
 * that can be applied to stylesheet to receive the same result
 * (used for Shadow CSS in Chrome extension)
 */
var patch = module.exports.patch = function(stylesheet, patches) {
    var self = this;
    if (typeof stylesheet === 'string') {
        stylesheet = this.stylesheets()[stylesheet];
    }

    if (!stylesheet || !stylesheet.cssRules) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(patches)) {
        patches = [patches];
    }

    var result = patches.map(function(patch) {
        var path = new NodePath(patch.path);
        var hints = patch.hints ? normalizeHints(patch.hints) : null;
        var index = self.createIndex(stylesheet);
        var location = pathfinder.find(index, path, hints);

        if (location.partial && patch.action === 'remove') {
            // node is absent, do nothing
            return;
        }

        if (!location.partial) {
            // exact match on node
            if (patch.action === 'remove') {
                var node = location.node;
                deleteRuleFromMatch(location);
                return resultOfDeletePatch(node);
            }
            return patchRule(location.node.ref, patch);
        }

        var out = [];
        var rule = setupFromPartialMatch(location, out);
        return out.concat(patchRule(rule, patch));
    }).filter(Boolean);

    return flatten(result);
};

var createIndex = module.exports.createIndex = function(ctx, parent) {
    var indexOf = function(item) {
        return this.children.indexOf(item);
    };

    if (!parent) {
        parent = {
            ix: -1,
            name: '',
            parent: null,
            children: [],
            ref: ctx,
            indexOf: indexOf
        };
    }

    var rules = ctx.cssRules;
    if (!rules) {
        return parent;
    }

    for (var i = 0, il = rules.length, rule, name, item; i < il; i++) {
        rule = rules[i];
        name = ruleName(rule);
        if (name === '@charset' || name === '@import') {
            continue;
        }

        item = {
            ix: i,
            name: normalizeSelector(name),
            parent: parent,
            children: [],
            ref: rule,
            indexOf: indexOf
        };

        parent.children.push(item);
        this.createIndex(rule, item);
    }

    return parent;
};

function last(arr) {
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
}

function flatten(input) {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, il = input.length, value; i < il; i++) {
        value = input[i];
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            output = output.concat(flatten(value));
        } else {
            output.push(value);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

function isTopLevel(node) {
    return node && node.parent && !node.parent.parent;
}

function resultOfDeletePatch(node) {
    if (isTopLevel(node)) {
        // matched top-level section, removed it
        return {
            action: 'delete',
            index: node.ix
        };
    }

    // matched inner node, mark top-level node as updated
    var ctx = node;
    while (ctx && !isTopLevel(ctx)) {
        ctx = ctx.parent;
    }

    if (ctx) {
        return {
            action: 'update',
            index: ctx.ix,
            value: ctx.ref.cssText
        };
    }
}

/**
 * Node path shim
 */
class NodePath {
    constructor(path) {
        this.components = [];
        if (Array.isArray(path)) {
            this.components = path.map(function(c) {
                return new NodePathComponent(c);
            });
        }
    }

    toString() {
        return this.components.map(function(c) {
            return c.toString(true);
        }).join('/');
    }
}

class NodePathComponent {
    constructor(name, pos) {
        if (Array.isArray(name)) {
            pos = name[1];
            name = name[0]
        }

        this.name = normalizeSelector(name);
        this.pos = pos || 1;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name +  (this.pos > 1 ? '|' + this.pos : '');
    }
}

function normalizeSelector(sel) {
    return sel.trim().replace(/:+(before|after)$/, '::$1');
}

/**
 * Findes all stylesheets in given context, including
 * nested `@import`s
 * @param  {StyleSheetList} ctx List of stylesheets to scan
 * @return {Object} Hash where key as a stylesheet URL and value
 * is a stylesheet reference
 */
function findStyleSheets(ctx, out) {
    out = out || {};
    for (var i = 0, il = ctx.length, url, item; i < il; i++) {
        item = ctx[i];
        url = item.href;
        if (url in out) {
            // stylesheet already added
            continue;
        }

        out[url] = item;

        // find @import rules
        // Firefox throws exception when accessing cssRules property 
        // of stylesheet from different origin
        try {
            if (item.cssRules) {
                for (var j = 0, jl = item.cssRules.length; j < jl; j++) {
                    if (item.cssRules[j].type == 3) {
                        findStyleSheets([item.cssRules[j].styleSheet], out);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {}
    }

    return out;
}

function atRuleName(rule) {
    /*
     * Reference:
     * UNKNOWN_RULE: 0
     * STYLE_RULE: 1
     * CHARSET_RULE: 2
     * IMPORT_RULE: 3
     * MEDIA_RULE: 4
     * FONT_FACE_RULE: 5
     * PAGE_RULE: 6
     * KEYFRAMES_RULE: 7
     * KEYFRAME_RULE: 8
     * SUPPORTS_RULE: 12
     * WEBKIT_FILTER_RULE: 17
     * HOST_RULE: 1001
     */
    switch (rule.type) {
        case 2: return '@charset';
        case 3: return '@import';
        case 4: return '@media ' + rule.media.mediaText;
        case 5: return '@font-face';
    }
}

/**
 * Returns name of given rule
 * @param  {CSSRule} rule
 * @return {String}
 */
function ruleName(rule) {
    var sel = rule.selectorText || atRuleName(rule);
    if (sel) {
        return sel;
    }

    var text = rule.cssText;
    if (text) {
        return (text.split('{', 2)[0] || '').trim();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns rule’s parent (stylesheet or rule)
 * @param  {CSSRule} rule
 * @return {CSSStyleSheet}
 */
function parent(rule) {
    return rule.parentRule || rule.parentStyleSheet;
}

/**
 * Check if given @-rule equals to given patch property
 * @param  {CSSRule} rule
 * @param  {Object}  prop
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
function atRuleEquals(rule, prop) {
    if (atRuleName(rule) !== prop.name) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (prop.name) {
        case '@charset':
            return rule.encoding === prop.value.trim().replace(/^['"]|['"]$/g, '');
        case '@import':
            return rule.href === prop.value.trim().replace(/^url\(['"]?|['"]?\)$/g, '');
    }
}

/**
 * Updates properties in given CSS rule
 * @param  {CSSRule} rule
 * @param  {Array} properties
 * @param  {Patch} patch
 */
function updateProperties(rule, properties, patch) {
    if (!rule || !rule.style) {
        return;
    }

    if ('ownerNode' in rule) {
        // A stylesheet (not CSS rule) cannot have properties;
        // updating them in Chrome gives unpredictable result
        return;
    }

    if (patch && patch.all) {
        // there are few challenges when changing updated
        // properies via CSSOM:
        // 1. Updating a a short-hand property only (for example,
        // `background` or `font`) will reset subsequent
        // full properties (`background-size`, `line-height` etc.)
        // that are not changed
        // 2. Chrome has buggy implementation of `background` shorthand:
        // at least it looses `background-size` property.
        // 
        // So right now the only valid and simple solution is to
        // re-apply all exising properties from source CSS even if they
        // were not updated or they doesn’t exist in current CSSOM rule
        properties = patch.all;
    }

    var style = rule.style;
    properties.forEach(function(p) {
        var important = null;
        var value = p.value.replace(/\!important\s*$/, function() {
            important = 'important';
            return '';
        })

        nameVariations(p.name).forEach(function(name) {
            style.setProperty(name, value, important);
        });
    });
}

function nameVariations(name) {
    var out = [name];
    if (name.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
        var camelCased = name.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, function(str, l) {
            return l.toUpperCase();
        });
        out.push(camelCased);
        if (name[0] === '-') {
            out.push(camelCased[0].toLowerCase() + camelCased.slice(1));
        }
    }
    return out;
}

/**
 * Updates given rule with data from patch
 * @param  {CSSRule} rule
 * @param  {Array} patch
 */
function patchRule(rule, patch) {
    var result = [];

    if (!rule) {
        // not a CSSStyleRule, aborting
        return result;
    }

    var reAt = /^@/, childRule;

    // remove properties
    patch.remove.forEach(function(prop) {
        if (reAt.test(prop)) {
            // @-properties are not properties but rules
            if (!rule.cssRules || !rule.cssRules.length) {
                return;
            }

            for (var i = 0, il = rule.cssRules.length; i < il; i++) {
                if (atRuleEquals(rule.cssRules[i], prop)) {
                    return rule.deleteRule(i);
                }
            }
        } else if (rule.style) {
            rule.style.removeProperty(prop.name);
        }
    });

    var updateRules = {
        '@charset': [],
        '@import': []
    };

    // update properties on current rule
    var properties = patch.update.filter(function(prop) {
        if (prop.name in updateRules) {
            updateRules[prop.name].push(prop);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });

    updateProperties(rule, properties, patch);

    // insert @-properties as rules
    while (childRule = updateRules['@charset'].pop()) {
        rule.insertRule(childRule.name + ' ' + childRule.value, 0);
        result.push({
            action: 'insert',
            index: 0,
            value: childRule.name + ' ' + childRule.value
        });
    }

    if (updateRules['@import'].length && rule.cssRules) {
        // @import’s must be inserted right after existing imports
        var childIx = 0, childName;
        for (var i = rule.cssRules.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            childName = atRuleName(rule.cssRules[i]);
            if (childName === '@charset' || childName === '@import') {
                childIx = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        while (childRule = updateRules['@import'].pop()) {
            rule.insertRule(childRule.name + ' ' + childRule.value, childIx);
            result.push({
                action: 'insert',
                index: childIx,
                value: childRule.name + ' ' + childRule.value
            });
        }
    }

    // find parent rule
    var ctx = rule;
    while (ctx.parentRule) {
        ctx = ctx.parentRule;
    }

    var ruleIx = -1;
    var allRules = ctx.parentStyleSheet && ctx.parentStyleSheet.cssRules;
    if (allRules) {
        for (var i = 0, il = allRules.length; i < il; i++) {
            if (allRules[i] === ctx) {
                ruleIx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (ruleIx !== -1) {
        result.push({
            action: 'update',
            index: ruleIx,
            value: ctx.cssText
        });
    }

    return result;
}

function setupFromPartialMatch(match, result) {
    // The `rest` property means we didn’t found exact section
    // where patch should be applied, but some of its parents.
    // In this case we have to re-create the `rest` sections
    // in best matching parent
    var accumulated = match.rest.reduceRight(function(prev, cur) {
        return cur.name + ' {' + prev + '}';
    }, '');

    var parent = match.parent;
    var insertIndex = parent.ref.cssRules ? parent.ref.cssRules.length : 0;
    if (match.node) {
        insertIndex = match.node.ix;
    }

    // console.log('Insert rule at index', insertIndex, match);
    try {
        var ix = parent.ref.insertRule(accumulated, insertIndex);
        if (!parent.ref.parentStyleSheet) {
            // inserted a top-level rule
            result.push({
                action: 'insert',
                index: ix,
                value: parent.ref.cssRules[ix].cssText
            });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn('LiveStyle:', e.message);
        return;
    }

    var ctx = parent.ref.cssRules[ix];
    var indexed = exports.createIndex(ctx);
    indexed.name = ruleName(ctx);
    indexed.ix = ix;
    parent.children.splice(match.index, 0, indexed);
    for (var i = match.index + 1, il = parent.children.length; i < il; i++) {
        parent.children[i].ix++;
    }

    while (ctx.cssRules && ctx.cssRules.length) {
        ctx = ctx.cssRules[0];
    }

    return ctx;
}

function deleteRuleFromMatch(match) {
    var result = null;
    try {
        parent(match.node.ref).deleteRule(match.node.ix);
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn('LiveStyle:', e);
        console.warn(match);
    }
    // console.log('Removed rule at index', match.node.ix);
    var ix = match.parent.children.indexOf(match.node);
    if (~ix) {
        match.parent.children.splice(ix, 1);
        for (var i = ix, il = match.parent.children.length, child; i < il; i++) {
            match.parent.children[i].ix--;
        }
    }
}

function normalizeHints(hints) {
    var comp = function(c) {
        return new NodePathComponent(c);
    };
    return hints.map(function(hint) {
        if (hint.before) {
            hint.before = hint.before.map(comp);
        }
        if (hint.after) {
            hint.after = hint.after.map(comp);
        }
        return hint;
    });
}
},{"./lib/split":2,"livestyle-pathfinder":3}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

/**
 * Splits given string by given separator with respect of
 * quoted substrings
 * @param  {String} str
 * @param  {String} sep
 * @return {Array}
 */
module.exports = function(str, sep) {
    var parts = [], start = 0, ch;
    for (var i = 0, il = str.length; i < il; i++) {
        ch = str[i];
        switch (ch) {
            case '\\': // skip escaped character
                i++;
                break;

            case '"': // skip quoted substring
            case "'":
                while (++i < il) {
                    if (str[i] === '\\') {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (str[i] === ch) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case sep:
                parts.push(str.substring(start, i));
                start = i + 1;
                break;
        }
    }

    parts.push(str.substring(start));
    return parts;
};
},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

/**
 * Tries to find the best insertion point for absent
 * path nodes (or its components).
 * @param  {ResolvedNode} tree
 * @param  {NodePath} path
 * @param  {Object} hints
 * @return {Object} Object with `parent` and `index` properties
 * pointing to matched element. The `rest` property (if present)
 * means given path can’t be fully matched and `index` property
 * points to `parent` child index where the `rest` node path
 * components should be added
 */
var find = module.exports.find = function(tree, path, hints) {
    if (path.toString() === '') {
        // it’s a root node
        return new SearchResult(tree);
    }

    hints = (hints || []).slice(0);
    var ctx = [tree], found;
    var components = path.components.slice(0);
    var component, hint, result;

    while (component = components.shift()) {
        hint = hints.shift();
        found = flatten(ctx.map(function(node) {
            return locate(node, component, hint);
        })).sort(matchesSort);

        found = found.filter(function(item) {
            return item.score === found[0].score;
        }).map(function(item) {
            return item.node;
        });

        if (!found.length) {
            // Component wasn’t found, which means
            // we have to create it, as well as all other
            // descendants.
            // So let’s find best insertion position, 
            // according to given hints
            components.unshift(component);
            result = last(ctx);
            return new SearchResult(result, indexForHint(result, hint), components);
        } else {
            ctx = found;
        }
    }

    result = last(ctx);
    return new SearchResult(result.parent, result.parent.indexOf(result));
}

/**
 * Returns best insertion position inside `parent`
 * for given hint
 * @param  {ResolvedNode} parent
 * @param  {Object} hint
 * @return {Number}
 */
var indexForHint = module.exports.indexForHint = function(parent, hint) {
    var items = parent.children;
    if (!hint) {
        return parent.children.length;
    }

    // XXX matchingSet() returns staring index of matching subset
    // but for our purposes we actually need the ending index
    var before = matchingSet(items, hint.before).map(function(ix) {
        return ix + hint.before.length;
    });
    var after = matchingSet(items, hint.after);
    var possibleResults = [];
    if (hint.before.length && hint.after.length) {
        // we have both sets of hints, find index between them
        before.forEach(function(ix) {
            for (var i = 0, il = after.length; i < il; i++) {
                if (after[i] >= ix) {
                    return possibleResults.push(after[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (hint.before.length) {
        possibleResults = before;
    } else if (hint.after.length) {
        possibleResults = after;
    }

    // insert nodes at the end by default
    return possibleResults.length ? possibleResults[0] : items.length;
}

function last(arr) {
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
}

function flatten(arr, ctx) {
    ctx = ctx || [];
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
        Array.isArray(item) ? flatten(item, ctx) : ctx.push(item);
    });
    return ctx;
}

function nodeName(node) {
    return node ? (node.normalName || node.name) : null;
}

class SearchResult {
    constructor(parent, index, rest) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.index = index;
        this.partial = !!rest;
        this.rest = rest;
    }

    get node() {
        if (typeof this.index === 'undefined') {
            return this.parent;
        }
        return this.parent.children[this.index];
    }
}

/**
 * Locates child nodes inside `ctx` that matches given 
 * path `component`. 
 * @param  {ResolvedNode}      ctx       Node where to search
 * @param  {NodePathComponent} component Path component to match
 * @param  {Object} hint       Location hint
 * @return {Array}  List of matched nodes, ordered by matching score
 */
function locate(ctx, component, hint) {
    var items = ctx.children.filter(function(child) {
        return nodeName(child) === component.name;
    });

    return items.map(function(node, i) {
        var score = 0;
        if (hint) {
            score += matchesBeforeHints(node, hint.before) ? 0.5 : 0;
            score += matchesAfterHints(node, hint.after) ? 0.5 : 0;
        } else if (i === component.pos - 1) {
            score += 0.1;
        }

        return {
            node: node,
            index: i,
            score: score
        };
    });
}

function matchesSort(a, b) {
    return (b.score * 10000 + b.index) - (a.score * 10000 + a.index);
}

function matchesBeforeHints(node, hints) {
    var siblings = node.parent.children;
    var ix = siblings.indexOf(node);

    if (!hints || hints.length - 1 > ix) {
        // more hints than siblings
        return false;
    }

    if (hints.length === ix === 0) {
        // hint tells it’s a first node
        return true;
    }

    for (var i = hints.length - 1, sibling; i >= 0; i--) {
        sibling = siblings[--ix];
        if (!sibling || nodeName(sibling) !== hints[i].name) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function matchesAfterHints(node, hints) {
    var siblings = node.parent.children;
    var ix = siblings.indexOf(node);

    if (!hints || ix + hints.length > siblings.length - 1) {
         // more hints than siblings
        return false;
    }

    if (hints.length === 0 && ix === siblings.length - 1) {
        // hint tells it’s a last node
        return true;
    }

    for (var i = 0, il = hints.length, sibling; i < il; i++) {
        sibling = siblings[++ix];
        if (!sibling || nodeName(sibling) !== hints[i].name) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function matchingSet(items, hints) {
    var result = [];
    if (!hints || !hints.length) {
        return result;
    }

    var hl = hints.length;
    items.forEach(function(item, i) {
        if (hints[0].name === nodeName(item)) {
            for (var j = 1; j < hl; j++) {
                if (!items[i + j] || nodeName(items[i +j]) !== hints[j].name) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            result.push(i);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
},{}],4:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } else { var newObj = {}; if (obj != null) { for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } newObj['default'] = obj; return newObj; } }

var _livestyleCssomPatcher = require('livestyle-cssom-patcher');

var cssom = _interopRequireWildcard(_livestyleCssomPatcher);

var _helpersShadowCss = require('./helpers/shadow-css');

var _helpersShadowCss2 = _interopRequireDefault(_helpersShadowCss);

var _helpersOrigin = require('./helpers/origin');

var _helpersOrigin2 = _interopRequireDefault(_helpersOrigin);

var pendingShadowCSSPatches = [];

function $$(sel, context) {
    var items = (context || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(items, 0);
}

function applyPatches(url, patches) {
    if (!url || !patches || !patches.length) {
        return;
    }

    var stylesheets = cssom.stylesheets();
    var originalCSS = stylesheets[url];
    if (!originalCSS) {
        // no such stylessheet, aborting
        return;
    }

    if (originalCSS.cssRules) {
        // console.log('apply patch %o on %o', patches, stylesheets[url]);
        cssom.patch(stylesheets[url], patches);
    } else {
        // Empty `cssRules` property means security restrictions applied
        // by Chrome. Try Shadow CSS
        var pending = !!pendingShadowCSSPatches.length;
        pendingShadowCSSPatches = pendingShadowCSSPatches.concat(patches);
        if (pending) {
            // there’s already a request for patching shadow, simply delegate
            // new patches to it
            return;
        }

        (0, _helpersShadowCss2['default'])(url).then(function (css) {
            // Empty pending patches as soon as possible so new patching request
            // can trigger new patching session even there was an error during
            // CSSOM syncing
            var patches = pendingShadowCSSPatches.slice(0);
            pendingShadowCSSPatches.length = 0;
            cssom.patch(css, patches).forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.action === 'delete') {
                    originalCSS.deleteRule(item.index);
                } else if (item.action === 'insert') {
                    originalCSS.insertRule(item.value, item.index);
                } else if (item.action === 'update') {
                    originalCSS.deleteRule(item.index);
                    originalCSS.insertRule(item.value, item.index);
                }
            });
        }, function (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        });
    }
}

function userStylesheets() {
    return $$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').filter(function (link) {
        return !!lsId(link);
    });
}

/**
 * Creates `amount` new stylesheets on current page
 * @param  {Number} amount How many stylesheets should be created
 * @returns {Array} Array of stylesheet URLs
 */
function generateUserStylesheets(url) {
    if (!Array.isArray(url)) {
        url = [url];
    }

    var result = {};
    url.forEach(function (internalUrl) {
        console.log('Creating stylesheet', internalUrl);
        var uss = createUserStylesheet();
        uss.dataset.livestyleId = internalUrl;
        document.head.appendChild(uss);
        result[internalUrl] = uss.href;
    });

    return result;
}

function createUserStylesheet(content) {
    var blob = new Blob([content || ''], { type: 'text/css' });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = url;
    return link;
}

function removeLink(link) {
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
}

/**
 * Findes all stylesheets in given context, including
 * nested `@import`s
 * @param  {StyleSheetList} ctx List of stylesheets to scan
 * @return {Array} Array of stylesheet URLs
 */
function findStyleSheets(ctx, out) {
    out = out || [];
    for (var i = 0, il = ctx.length, url, item; i < il; i++) {
        item = ctx[i];
        url = item.href;
        if (~out.indexOf(url) || lsId(item.ownerNode)) {
            // stylesheet already added or it’s a user stylesheet
            continue;
        }

        if (url) {
            out.push(url);
        }
/**
 * Shadow CSS is a concept used to bypass Chrome security restrictions for CSSOM:
 * if a stylesheet is loaded from different origin or 'file:' protocol, you cannot
 * access its `cssRules`. But `insertRule()` and `deleteRule()` works fine though.
 *
 * Here’s how Shadow CSS works:
 * 1. Loads contents of given (security restricted) stylesheet either from
 * DevTools resource (faster, contains most recent changes) or via XHR 
 * (extensions can bypass CORS restrictions).
 * 2. Creates inline style with this stylesheet contents in hidden iframe. This
 * stylesheets always allows access to `cssRules`.
 * 3. Use this inline stylesheet for CSSOM patching. The patching will return 
 * an update plan: a set of `insterRule()` and `deleteRule()` instructions that
 * must be applied to origin stylesheet to get the same result.
 * 4. Blindly apply this update plan to original stylesheet and hope everything
 * works as expected.
 * 5. Automatically keep track of all DevTools Resources updates and keep 
 * shadow CSS in sync.
 */
'use strict';
```

Как решить проблему с ней ? что не так с этим скриптом и вообще откуда он?

Comment: Во-первых, какая ошибка? Во-вторых, вы правда думаете что кто-то будет читать эту портянку?

Comment: Добавил скрин и еще - почтите текст в самом низу кода

Comment: Ну у вас ошибка в каком-то экстеншне. Выключите его

Comment: где хотя бы искать ? где выключить экстеншн?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en

Comment: Нашел! Ошибка расширение Emmet LiveStyle. Спасибо всем, кто помог!